# Select from TableA.Code if IN TableB.Code

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

```
Table1

ID, CODE


Table 2 

ID, CODE
```

I want to select ALL Records from Table 1 Where Table1.Code exists in Table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM table2 WHERE table2.CODE = table1.CODE)
```